# ExtJS 4.2.1 - issue with refs and controllers

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, controller

I have my label defined as follows:

```
Ext.define('CapHour.view.CapHourLabel', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Label',

    alias: 'widget.caphourlabel',

    //itemId: 'capHourLabel',
    itemId: 'label',

    style: 'display:inline-block;text-align:center'
})
```

And my controller defined like this:

```
Ext.define('CapHour.controller.CapHourController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    stores: ['CapHour'],

    refs: [
        {
            ref: 'label',
            selector: 'label'
        }
    ],

    init: function() {
        var store = this.getCapHourStore();

        store.on('load', function(records, operation, success) {
            var label = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#label')[0],
            //var label = this.getCapHourLabel(),
                hour = records.getAt(0).get('hour');

            label.setText('CAP HOUR<br/>'+hour, false);
        })
    }
})
```

I can use `Ext.ComponentQuery.query()` just fine, but when I try to use `this.getLabel()`, the API call returns `undefined`.  Is there something I'm forgetting?  I tried setting the selector in the ref to 'label' and '#label' but I keep getting the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the scope of the store callback to be the controller:

```
store.load({
    scope: this,
    callback: function(records) {
        console.log(this.getLabel());
    }
});
```

As a side note, you'll probably want a better selector. The current selector you have searches by xtype, globally, so that means 'grab the first thing you see that has an xtype label'.

Comment: wow thx it worked.  Yeah, about the selector, I ended up setting the itemId to capHourLabel instead.  In my refs, I set the selector to '#capHourLabel' and it worked. :)

Comment: Quick question...why does this.getLabel() return undefined in the scope of the controllers init function?

Comment: Because it hasn't been created yet.

Comment: Ok, thx.  I read in the docs that init gets called before launch executes and the viewport is created.  Makes sense.